# ORDER BY null position

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there a way to specify where to place `null` values in a sorted list?

I have a list I'd like to sort in descending order. I want nodes with `date=null` to be included, just at the end of the list.

Looking for something like this in cypher:

`ORDER BY date DESC NULLS LAST`

> From Neo4j:
>
> When sorting the result set, NULL will always come at the end of the
>   result set for ascending sorting, and first when doing descending
>   sort.
>
> http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#order-by-ordering-null

Comment: Could you select where not null, order that and then union select where null? It's a bit wordy but...

Comment: I could but that would be unnecessarily costly. There are only a number of nodes with the date property as null, out of about 5000 in total. Basically, only those that go to the last pages would see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following :
ORDER BY date IS NULL DESC

Comment: Using `ORDER BY date IS NOT NULL DESC` worked. Thanks!

Comment: @lifwanian This does not work. Rows with a value of NULL are at the end, but other rows are not sorted in descending order.

Comment: in that case you can either set a second order by like ORDER BY date IS NOT NULL DESC, date DESC. It is actually ordering on boolean. So, all record having null is 1 and other are 0.

Comment: @AshokM.Prajapati A good option with a second sorting. It will be interesting to see the results of profiling in comparison with the option with coalesce.

Comment: @stdob, you're correct, I jumped the gun. Both sorting twice and your answer seems to work. Profiling returns same # of db hits for both too.

Comment: `COALESCE(A.date, -1) DESC` should be accepted answer

Answer (score 4):

You can sort by result of [`COALESCE`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#functions-coalesce).

For example we have the following nodes:

```
MERGE (A1:Test {name:'a1'}) 
MERGE (A2:Test {name:'a2', date: 1})
MERGE (A3:Test {name:'a3', date: 2})
MERGE (A4:Test {name:'a4'})
```

We can sort the following manner:

```
MATCH (A:Test)
RETURN A.name, 
       A.date 
ORDER BY 
       COALESCE(A.date, -1) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use `coalesce()` in your `ORDER BY`?

```
ORDER BY coalesce(val, 0)
```